# out of memory within a function - what do i do?

Tags: c++

I was recently asked how i should resolve a problem  (In C++) if a function runs out of memory for example if you allocate too much memory within a function. How would you overcome this issue?

many thanks

Comment: You should write a better function that doesn't allocate as much memory

Comment: I would buy more memory.

Comment: It depends on whether you are implementing a social networking site or writing software for the mission to Mars.

Comment: Try logging the failure to give you a hint on where and why it happened, then try to do a clean shutdown of your application.

Comment: ok all of you guys would have failed the interview also :)

Comment: Also, how you handle an out-of-memory condition would be quite different in C vs. C++, which are the two tags you have on this question. There is no way to provide a reasonable answer to this question without a lot more context...

Comment: it was a C++ question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it very much depends on the type of system you are writing.
However, generally speaking, the first thing you should do is print a good and descriptive error message.
Adding more RAM is not an option on some systems.
You may also need to increment an appropriate statistics counter.
It may not be appropriate to exit the application. Realtime applications, for example, often times run out of heap space during heavy load, but they do not shut down. They simply fail to allocate memory until system load returns to normal.

I disagree with fvu, who suggested moving stack variables to the heap for the following reasons:
1. If the problem is that you run out of stack space, you will not (in most systems) be able to detect that. A stack overrun is a very difficult problem to track down, unless you have appropriate checks.
2. Since the requirement your interviewer stated is that you CAN detect the memory allocation failure, it is because your heap is depleted. Moving your stack variables to be instantiated on the heap is, therefore, a bad idea.

Comment: ok so how would you approach the problem?

Comment: As I said:
1. output a clear error message to log
2. increment an appropriate statistics counter
3. reject the request (obviously)
4. you may need to stay up and running, until the system is back to normal load
5. or, if this is an application without uptime requirements shut down gracefully, releasing any resources you may have allocated.

This is not a one answer fits all question. It all depends on the system requirements. And this is exactly what your interviewer wanted to hear: that you understand there are many varying requirements, depending on the system.
Hope this helps.

Comment: what do you mean by statistics counter?

Comment: In realtime systems, where you normally do not shut down the application, you will have various statistics counters reporting the current state of the system, and various events that have happened.
The 'out_of_memory' counter is a pretty common one.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the stuff that is currently not needed to the hard-disk, then deallocate it and breathe again.

Answer (score 0):

You simply write more efficient code to not take up such huge chunk of memory, and if you can't do anything more efficient then buy more memory.
Sorry I did copy answers that aaronman and andre said, but that is what comes to my mind too.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think your interviewer wanted to know whether you are able to differentiate between stack-allocated variables (where variables declared inside a function body live) and heap-allocated variables (the others).  Among other reasons this difference is quite important as the stack is typically more constrained than the heap.

So a valid response - if optimizing the variables away isn't an option - would be to move them from the stack to the heap.  How?

1. by declaring the variable outside of the function body
2. by `malloc`'ing the required room

Of course, that would lead to a next question, as they both create other challenges, eg:

1. concurrency issues and variable visibility
2. C has no garbage collector, so `malloc`'ed stuff needs to be `free`'d

...

Comment: you know i gave a similar response, basically malloc within the function but i still failed the interview :)

Comment: heap is heap anyway it does not matter where you allocate it main or within a function

Comment: As I was not present during your interview, I cannot comment on why you failed...  There are 1000's of ways to shoot yourself in the foot with `malloc` in C and you probably stepped into a trap that the friendly interviewer set up for you.

Comment: or he was having a bad day... It was my assumption that the heap has more memory, are you sure this is true?

Comment: By default the stack will be just a few MB (in Linux stacksize is managed by the OS and default is ~8MB, in Windows/Visual Studio the default is 1MB).  To return back to your original issue, did you specifically ask the interviewer why you failed?  And if it was related to the allocation thing, I think it was probably more related to what was asked&answered after that initial question, in itself using malloc is a valid answer...

Answer (score 0):

In C++, that would cause a `throw bad_alloc;` inside of `new` or whatever is performing the allocation.

Which means the code will automatically end up in the (suitable) catch-block nearest outside of where the allocation call is. At that point, there are lots of different choices.

However, "overcoming" out of memory is not something you can say what you do in generic terms - it will very much depend on why you are out of memory, what the application is supposed to do, what other allocations exist (perhaps we can free some data that isn't absolutely necessary to keep around - such as some caches-tables used to get better performance, but if you don't have them, it still works). Or you could just pop up a message to say "Out of memory, exiting".